# Regex alternation construct eats part of previous group

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to fashion a Regex to capture a function style argument list, which should be straight forward enough, but I'm encountering a behaviour I don't understand.

In the snippet below the first example behaves as you would expect, capturing the function name into the first group and the argument list into the second group.

In the second example I want to replace the 'zero or more' quantifier that captures the argument list with the 'one or more' quantifier so that the second group will fail if there are no arguments. I'm expecting the regex to capture just the function name, but for some reason the regex is eating the '1' off the end of the function name, and I cannot for the life of me see why it would be doing that. Can anyone see what's going wrong with this please?

```cs
// {func1} {blah, blah, blah}
Match m13 = Regex.Match("func1(blah, blah, blah)", @"(\w+) (?([(]) [(]([^)]*) )",
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// {func}
Match m14 = Regex.Match("func1()", @"(\w+) (?([(]) [(]([^)]+) )",
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression can be adjusted to:

```
(\w+) (?([(]) [(]([^)]*) )
                      ^ rather than +
```

The reason the expression returns an unexpected result relates to backtracking.  The regex engine effectively takes the following steps:

1. `(\w)` matches `func1`.
2. `func1` is immediately followed by a `(`, matching the zero-width expression in the conditional matching construct.
3. The conditional construct requires a `(` literal followed by one or more characters that are not `)`.  **This condition fails for the input `func1()`, since there are zero characters between `(` and `)`.**
4. The engine backtracks to step (1) and removes a character, so that `(\w)` now matches `func` instead of `func1`.
5. `func` is immediately followed by a `1`, which does not satisfy the zero-width expression in the conditional matching construct.
6. Since the conditional matching construct does not match and there is no alternate expression, the regex completes successfully with `func` in the first captured group, and no match in the second captured group.

The issue emerges in Step 3, where the expression fails to allow `()` as a legal argument list.  Adjusting the expression to allow zero characters between the opening and closing parentheses (as illustrated above) allows this sequence.  An expression such as  `^(\w+)(?:\((.*)\))?$` may also address the underlying issue without the need for a conditional construct.

Comment: That's a useful analysis of what's going on but it leaves the question why does the engine backtrack a character if the alternation construct fails? (\w+) is unequivocally greedy so if the alternation construct fails then why wouldn't that just register as a failed unmatched group?

Comment: @Neutrino The `+` operator is greedy but not possessive, that is, it can still backtrack if doing so is necessary for the match to succeed.  (The equivalent .NET possessive expression, `(?>(\w+))`, will not backtrack and behave in the way you describe.)